# IpAddress is getting null with use of HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ip Address is getting null, when I,m using it in assembly file.
Below are my code:

```
var forwardedFor = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"].ToString();
var userIpAddress = String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(forwardedFor) ?
   HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"] : forwardedFor.Split(',').Select(s => s.Trim()).First();
```

Comment: You misspelled the header name.

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in the header name.

Instead of:

`HTTP_X_FO0RWARDED_FOR`

Try :

`HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR`

Comment: yes you are right, still getting null. It can get Ipaddress from REMOTE_ADDR